# Можно ли убрать второе тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вставная-конструкция

> Тогда меня решили отдать в кружок керамики — ведь в таком случае мне нужно было работать руками, — потом меня отдали обучаться верховой езде, но и здесь я не показала выдающихся результатов.

Можно ли второе тире не ставить?

Если два тире, то конструкция ***ведь в таком случае мне нужно было работать руками*** является вставной.

А если убрать второе тире, то ***чем*** она является?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: «Тогда меня решили отдать в кружок керамики — ведь в таком случае мне нужно было работать руками, — а потом отдали обучаться верховой езде, но и здесь я не показала выдающихся результатов». (Предложение немного подкорректировано).

Пояснение:

Вставная конструкция выделяется тире с двух сторон, но в подобных случаях особое внимание уделяется постановке запятых (одна или две запятые). В нашем случае ставится вторая запятая, разделяющая простые предложения.

Для сравнении:  Она повесила трубку – аппарат был рядом, – но ещё долго молчала (запятая разделяет однородные члены).

В то же время иногда одна из запятых ставится для симметрии, например:

Когда Косте пошёл девятый годок, –  я же в ту пору уже невестой была, – повезла я его по всем гимназиям. Первая запятая ставится для симметрии.

Answer (score 1):

Вставную конструкцию можно взять в скобки и отделить запятой.Тогда меня решили отдать в кружок керамики(ведь в таком случае мне нужно было работать руками)**,**потом меня отдали обучаться верховой езде, но и здесь я не показала выдающихся результатов.